# Laravel Artisan: Using a remote database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I am using Laravel 5.1, trying to run `php artisan migrate` on my local computer. I have my `.env` file set up with the credentials of a remote database.

However, upon running, I get an error (replaced real details for security):

```
Access denied for user 'user'@'44.55.66.77' to database 'db_laravel'
```

It appears that for some reason, it is attempting to run the command on my local IP, which is `44.55.66.77` instead of the remote database. I have already tried allowing remote access to the database from my IP, however I am still having the same issue.

I have also already attempted to connect to the database using its IP, to no avail.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Update:** Okay, I read some of my host's documentation, and tried using % as a wildcard to allow any IP access to the database. I now get `Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'db_laravel'`. However, still not sure what is going on.

Comment: is the user allowed access from remote? What port are you using? There's a little bit more to DB access permissions than having a username, password, and a DB

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes, as I mentioned I gave the user remote access. Should I be using a port in Laravel's `.env` file?

Comment: Did you flush the privileges? Is the default MySQL port exposed (3306)? PS: There's a DBA site that deals with access setup and DB config... that site might be a better fit for your question

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Everything with MySQL is set as it should be. I am not understanding how Artisan is attempting to connect to my local IP instead of my database, as should be the case. I do not think it is even able to attempt to connect to the database.

Comment: did you set `MYSQL_HOST` to the remote host in your env file?

Comment: @andrewtweber I see `DB_HOST` which is set to the remote database. Also `database.php` is set with the same information as well.

Comment: @joexanderson The error is stating that the user 'user'@'44.55.66.77' is denied access, not that you're trying to connect to a database located at 44.55.66.77

Comment: @Wader Right, however I cannot figure out why it is trying to connect to '44.55.66.77' and not my database. That IP is my home's IP address.

Comment: Try running `php artisan tinker` and in tinker run this `Config::get('database');`. Is the host for your remote db the one you expect it? If not then the configuration is not loaded how you're expecting it to. In that case please post the contents of  `.env` as well as `config/database.php`.

Comment: @Bogdan Yes, the host is the one I set, the remote host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the issue. It was a problem with my host not properly accepting the IP I entered for allowing remote access. All is well now. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

This "'user'@'44.55.66.77'" means that user is connecting FROM ip "44.55.66.77", not TO "44.55.66.77".

Comment: So any tips on troubleshooting this issue?